# Android Multiple RecyclerView last position not persisting

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, focus

I am using 2 RecyclerViews with different image sizes in the Recycler Item, and the attached image gives more idea about the UI.
I am developing this app for an Android TV. 
The issue I am facing here is, while I shift the focus from one recylerView to another , and come back to the previous recyclerview the focus does not come to the last selected item. The focus moves to the nearest item on the next recyclerView.

Hence my question is how to manage this behavior of focus and last state of recyclerView here.

MyHomeFragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tv1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />

      <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/rv1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:clipChildren="true"
          android:clipToPadding="true" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tv2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />

      <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/rv2"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:clipChildren="true"
          android:clipToPadding="true" />

  </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: post your `code` you have tried.

Comment: @JakirHossain : xml code posted

Comment: @JakirHossain : any suggestions. ??